# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. errpr

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a datagridview and a label. I want to print value of dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0] to label1. Here I write a code. But it gives an error.

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   label3.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();                
}
```

Comment: Well you've got a lot of dereferencing there. Maybe `dataGridView2` is null. Or `label3`. Or `dataGridView2.Rows[i]`. Or `dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0]`. Or `dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value`. Have you done any diagnostic work to find out what?

Comment: I honestly think that the FAQ here should include a video tutorial on how to do basic debugging. Seriously, there's like 60 `NullRef` questions per day.

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` probably contains `NULL`. You cannot call `.ToString()` on a `NULL` value. You should first check the value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
        label3.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
     else 
        label3.Text = "";
}
```